# bean validation not working with kotlin (JSR 380)

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, bean-validation, jsr380

so first of all i could not think of a better title for this question so i'm open for changes.

I am trying to validate a bean using the bean validation mechanism (JSR-380) with spring boot.

So i got a controller like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
class UserController {
    @PostMapping
    fun createUser(@Valid user: User, bindingResult: BindingResult): ModelAndView {
        return ModelAndView("someview", "user", user)
    }
}
```

with this being the User class written in kotlin:

```
data class User(
    @field:NotEmpty
    var roles: MutableSet<@NotNull Role> = HashSet()
)
```

and this being the test:

```
@Test
internal fun shouldNotCreateNewTestWithInvalidParams() {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/users")
        .param("roles", "invalid role"))
        .andExpect(model().attributeHasFieldErrors("user",  "roles[]"))
}
```

**Invalid Roles are mapped to null.**

As you can see i want `roles` to contain at least one item with none of the items being null. 
However when testing the above code no binding errors are reported if `roles` contains null values. It does report an error if the set is empty though.
I was thinking that this might be an issue with how kotlin code compiles as the same code works just fine when the User class is written in java. Like this:

```
@Data // just lombok...
public class User {
    @NotEmpty
    private Set<@NotNull Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Same Controller, same test.

After checking the bytecode i noticed that the kotlin version is not including the nested `@NotNull` annotation (see below).

Java:

```
private Ljava/util/Set; roles
@Ljavax/validation/constraints/NotEmpty;()
@Ljavax/validation/constraints/NotNull;() : FIELD, 0;
@Ljavax/validation/constraints/NotEmpty;() : FIELD, null
```

Kotlin:

```
private Ljava/util/Set; roles
@Ljavax/validation/constraints/NotEmpty;()
@Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // added because roles is not nullable in kotlin. this does not affect validation
```

Now the question is why?

**Here's a [sample project](https://github.com/DarkAtra/jsr380-kotlin-issue) in case you want to try some stuff.**

Comment: before \@NotEmpty just ad \@NotNull in class user and Try

Comment: still fails with `java.lang.AssertionError: No errors for field 'roles[]' of attribute 'userDto'` and it actually makes sense in this case as adding `@NotNull` to roles will only ensure that `roles` is never null. However i want to validate the items inside of `roles`.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem. I think I will have to create custom validators for the time being. https://twitter.com/GlowinskiRafal/status/1043183121796083718

Comment: @TommySchmidt I have created a Kotlin issue using all the details you have provided: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27049 - I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @RafalG. i dont mid at all. thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Answer (Kotlin 1.3.70)

Make sure to compile the kotlin code with jvm target 1.8 or greater and enable this feature by providing the `-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations` when compiling.

For Spring Boot projects you only have to do the following changes (tested with Spring Boot 2.3.3 and Kotlin 1.4.0):

1. In your pom set the following property:

   ```
   <properties>
       <java.version>11</java.version>
       <kotlin.version>1.4.0</kotlin.version>
   </properties>
   ```
2. Add `<arg>-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations</arg>` to the `kotlin-maven-plugin`:

   ```
   <build>
       <plugin>
           <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
           <configuration>
               <args>
                   <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                   <arg>-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations</arg>
               </args>
               <compilerPlugins>
                   <plugin>spring</plugin>
               </compilerPlugins>
           </configuration>
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                   <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                   <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>
       </plugin>
   </build>
   ```

[Sample Project](https://github.com/DarkAtra/jsr380-kotlin-issue)

[Jetbrains Release Notes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew14.html#type-annotations-in-the-jvm-bytecode)

---

### Workaround (pre Kotlin 1.3.70)

[Rafal G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743716/rafal-g) already pointed out that we could use a custom validator as a workaround. So here's some code:

**The Annotation:**

```
import javax.validation.Constraint
import javax.validation.Payload
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget.CONSTRUCTOR
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget.FIELD
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget.TYPE_PARAMETER
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

@MustBeDocumented
@Constraint(validatedBy = [NoNullElementsValidator::class])
@Target(allowedTargets = [FUNCTION, FIELD, ANNOTATION_CLASS, CONSTRUCTOR, VALUE_PARAMETER, TYPE_PARAMETER])
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class NoNullElements(
    val message: String = "must not contain null elements",
    val groups: Array<KClass<out Any>> = [],
    val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = []
)
```

**The ConstraintValidator:**

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext

class NoNullElementsValidator : ConstraintValidator<NoNullElements, Collection<Any>> {
    override fun isValid(value: Collection<Any>?, context: ConstraintValidatorContext): Boolean {
        // null values are valid
        if (value == null) {
            return true
        }
        return value.stream().noneMatch { it == null }
    }
}
```

**And finally the updated User class:**

```
data class User(
    @field:NotEmpty
    @field:NoNullElements
    var roles: MutableSet<Role> = HashSet()
)
```

---

Altough validation works now, the resulting ConstrainViolation is slightly different. For example the `elementType` and `propertyPath` differs as you can see below.

**Java:**

[image: The Java Version]

**Kotlin:**

[image: The Kotlin Version]

Source is available here: https://github.com/DarkAtra/jsr380-kotlin-issue/tree/workaround

Thanks again for your help [Rafal G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743716/rafal-g)

Comment: Seems like they've added support for this feature in kotlin 1.3.70: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-3-70-released/

Comment: I confirmed that the validation is working without `<arg>-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations</arg>` in spring boot 2.4.4 with java 8 version and kotlin 1.4.31

Comment: @mazend do you have an example for that? during my tests, `<arg>-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations</arg>` is still required even with kotlin `1.5.10` and spring boot `2.5.0`.

See: https://github.com/DarkAtra/jsr380-kotlin-issue/tree/j8-sb2.4.4-kt1.4.31

Comment: I've downloaded your code. um.. Why don't you add simple logging and check result?
'
 @PostMapping
 fun createUserKotlin(@Valid user: de.darkatra.jsr380kotlinissue.kotlin.User, bindingResult: BindingResult): ModelAndView {
  println("bindingResult.hasErrors() = ${bindingResult.hasErrors()}")
  return ModelAndView("someview", "user", user)
 }
'

Comment: @mazend i've just updated the code (see the above link) and this is the log message i got: `bindingResult.hasErrors() = false`

(make sure to run the code with `mvn clean verify`)

Comment: It's weird. I got the same result with you when I run the `UserControllerTest`. However when I send empty POST request from POSTMAN, both cases show `bindingResult.hasErrors() = true`. It seems `AutoConfigureMockMvc` not working without `<arg>-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations</arg>`. How do you think about it? Actually I'm not familiar with Spring Test.

Comment: you're probably seeing `bindingResult.hasErrors() = true` because sending an empty post request violates the `@field:NotEmpty` constraint on the roles field. my test case on the other hand violates the `@NotNull` constraint inside the `MutableSet` because in the test `not a role` is converted to `null` via https://github.com/DarkAtra/jsr380-kotlin-issue/blob/j8-sb2.4.4-kt1.4.31/src/main/kotlin/de/darkatra/jsr380kotlinissue/RoleConverter.kt

Comment: It seems you are right. so we need to include `<arg>-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations</arg>` to validate all constraints?

Comment: yes, without `<arg>-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations</arg>` the kotlin compiler discards all `TYPE_PARAMETER` annotations (e.g. annotations on generics) - you can also see the difference in the corresponding bytecode (see question)

Answer (score 16):

Try adding `?` like this:

```
data class User(
    @field:Valid
    @field:NotEmpty
    var roles: MutableSet<@NotNull Role?> = HashSet()
)
```

Then the kotlin compiler should realise roles could be `null`, and it might honor the validation, I know little about JSR380 so i'm just guessing though.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Sadly, adding a ? to Role does not make any difference. It seems to be a bug/missing feature in kotlin right now as of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13228. I will update my question and point to a workaround until it is fixed.

Comment: This is best answer! Thank you!!!

Comment: Making type class nullable just in sake of validation is not really clean approach.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The solution was to add this dependency:

```
 implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation"
```

Without this dependency, the REST controller was working but no exception was thrown when the `javax.validation` bean constraints were not honored. Now it throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

Comment: What a lifesaver, thank you for sharing this! I thought it was due to some Kotlin issue.