# spring rest @RequestBody does not validate with @Valid

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rest

I'm learning java and spring boot and I am trying to validate a controller parameter which was bound from json.

I've got simple Entity:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
class Resource {
    @NotBlank
    String uri;
}
```

Which I want to persist through the following controller:

```java
@BasePathAwareController
public class JavaResourcePostController {

    private final ResourceRepository repository;

    public JavaResourcePostController(ResourceRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/resources", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<Resource> create(
        @Valid @RequestBody Resource resource
    ) {
        repository.save(resource);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(resource);
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the resource argument should be valid when entering the method. But posting an empty `uri` field does not trigger the validation of the method. it does however get triggered in the hibernate validation in `repository.save()`

Why does the `@Valid` annotation on the argument not ensure I get a validated entity?

Comment: Try adding `@Validated`to your controller. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html

Comment: This works when I annotation `@Validated` on the class level idd! I only tried this on the argument and method. can you post this as an answer, so this can be accepted and closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add [`@Validated`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) to your controller class.

Comment: This idd solved the issue, any idea why this doesnt work in kotlin, only in java?

Comment: to get it working in kotlin I also needed to add the spring plugin to the kotlin maven plugin as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52345291/bean-validation-not-working-with-kotlin-jsr-380