# @Valid not working with @RequestBody in Spring3.0.5

Tags: spring-mvc

@Valid is not working with RequestBody in Sptring 3.0.5. Below is code snippets . Please suggest what is causing the issue.

pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

Conroller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ValidateCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="content-type=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String validateCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer) throws Exception {
// further processing"

return "Validated";
}
```

Customer class:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


public class Customer {
    
    
    @NotNull
    private String userId;
    
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
    
    @NotNull
    private String companyName;
/* getter and setter methods */
}
```

Below is the payload requested from postman which should fail to the request, but receiving success message.

{
"firstName":"abc",
"lastName": "xyz",
"companyName":"abc Corp"
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring rest @RequestBody does not validate with @Valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70340575/spring-rest-requestbody-does-not-validate-with-valid)

Comment: Seems @Validated not supported in Spring3.0.5